# Event-based unit tests fail with "done() called multiple times"

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, eventemitter

I have a simple async callback test that I've set up with `mocha`:

```
describe('test', function () {
    it('should not work', function(done) {
        client.on('success', function () {
          return done('client saw success message but should have errored');
        });
        client.on('error', function (err) {
          return done();
        });
    });
});
```

The idea is that the client does some async operation and should receive an error event. If it receives anything else, then the test should fail.

Unfortunately, `mocha` keeps complaining:

```
done() called multiple times
```

I've done all sorts of things to verify that this is not true. For example, I've tried throwing an error before the `done` in the success handler, logging when control reaches the success handler, etc.

How can I get this test to run without telling me I'm calling `done` twice? I would throw an error instead of calling `done` with an error message, but that would cause the test to fail with a timeout instead of the error I want.

Comment: You need to remove the event listeners from `client` in that test once the test is finished. You are probably reusing the same `client` object in a following test which causes the previous test's event listeners to refire

Comment: The confusing thing is that this is the only test I've written (and I don't see any logs saying 'success' is fired when I add that in). I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: I'll write up an answer for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your tests are failing because you are **still listening for events after the
test is finished**.

A completed test doesn't automatically remove the event listeners.

On your next test you are firing the event again but previous test event
listeners  are called again since they are still listening for the event.
Since `done` was already called on them when that test completed,
they fire again hence you get the error that `done was called multiple times`.

Couple of options here:

- You can remove the event listeners after each test by using a named function.
- You can use the [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_handling_events_only_once) listener.

### Removing event listeners via a named function:

```
describe('test', () => {  
  it('should work', done => {
    const finish = err => {
      done(err)
      client.removeListener('success', finish)
      client.removeListener('error', finish)
    }

    client.on('error', finish)    
    client.on('success', result => {
      result.should.equal('foo')
      // rest of tests for result...

      finish()
    })

    client.fireEvent()
  })  
})
```

Note that you might need to use `off` or `removeEventListener` instead of `removeListener` - whichever method your `client` uses to remove a listener.

### Using the [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_handling_events_only_once) listener:

Alternatively, you can use the [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_handling_events_only_once) listener to listen for events. Like the name suggests, this handler fires only once so there's no need to manually remove listeners afterwards.

```
describe('test', function () {  
  it('should work', done => {

    client.once('error', done)
    client.once('success', result => {
      result.should.equal('foo')
      // rest of tests for result...

      done()
    })

    client.fireEvent()
  })
})
```

**Warning:** These methods have an important caveat. They don't allow you to test the edge case on whether your `client` actually fires the event *just once*. If `client` erroneously fires `success` more than once your test would erroneously succeed as well. I'm not sure how you can handle this gracefully at this time but comments are welcome.